# Angular - Scroll to top button

Tags: angular

I have a page where I accept or decline data.
After accepting component reload data to next set and scroll to the top of the page.

I have a problem with that scrolling. Apparently window.scroll(0,0) doesn't work when triggered while loading data. I used ngAfterContentChecked(), but then the page is scrolling even after just button click (without confirmation in a dialog).
And now I have something like this.

BTW. I can't change route params, I've tried document.body... etc

```
  reload: boolean = false;
  contentToReload: number = 6;

  public ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
    if(this.reload){
      this.contentToReload--;
      if(this.contentToReload == 0)
      {
        this.blockUI.stop();
        window.scroll(0,0); //for edge
        window.scrollTo(0,0); //for chrome
        this.contentToReload = 6;
        this.reload = false;
      }
    }
  }


public setAsCorrect(): void {
    this.dataService.setAsCorrect(this.data)
      .subscribe(apiResult => {
        if (apiResult.result.isAnyDataLeft) {
          this.reload = true;
          this.getData();
        }
        else {
          this.RoutingService.navigateTo(null);
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Did you try `document.querySelector('#ID_OF_ELEMENT').scrollIntoView();` ?

Comment: Yes, didn't work

Comment: The simplest working solution is `window.setTimeout(()=>window.scrollTo(0,0),5000)`